# Will Ubuntu 11.04 run on a 1.60 GHz Atom 230?

Tags: installation, 11.04, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

I am new to Ubuntu, Currently I am working with Windows XP on my system.

I would like to install Ubuntu 11.4 version Software on my system.

My system configuration is:

```
Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU 230 a 1.60 GHZ System and 1 GB Ram
```

1. Is this version working fine for this configuration, or I should go for another lower version of Ubuntu? If you have any alternative please tell me.
2. Does this version have built in audio and video drivers with VLC Media player or should I install it separately?

We didn't have net specility.

Please give me some idea about these.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware).

The short answer is that your system should run any version of Ubuntu without problems.

Furthermore, you can improve performance by running a lightweight derivative Ubuntu (as explained there) instead of an old version.

While 11.04 will run, it's end-of-life--you should use a version of Ubuntu that's currently suported. You'll probably want a version that will be supported for more than a few more months, so your options are 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: Try **12.04 LTS** first, then experiment with 12.10 (or event wait for 13.04).